# Multi Threading in web application

Tags: java, multithreading, web

I have class which is used to display the current location in the bread crumb.
This class is getting initialised per user from the front end.
**my question is  do I need to synchronise the methods in this class** if yes which are methods needs to be  synchronised .There is some confusion. so please advise.

```
public class CrumbNav {

    private Stack<Crumb> stack;
    private Crumb crumb;

    public CrumbNav() {
        stack = new Stack<Crumb>();
        crumb = new Crumb("Home");
        stack.push(crumb);
    }


    public void addcrumb(String current) {          
        Crumb newCrumb = new Crumb(current);
        if (stack.peek().equals(newCrumb)) {
            return;
        }
        stack.push(newCrumb);
    }

    public void removeCurrent() {
        stack.pop();
    }

    public void eraseTrail() {
        stack.clear();
        stack.push(crumb);
    }

    public void removeCrumbsClicked(Crumb selected) {
        while (true) {
            if (stack.peek().equals(selected) || stack.isEmpty())
                break;

            stack.pop();
        }
    }

    public Crumb getLastBreadCrumb() {
        return stack.lastElement();
    }

    public Crumb getPreviousCrumb() {
        if (stack.size() > 1) {
            return stack.get(stack.size() - 2);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public List<Crumb> getCrumbTrail() {
        return stack.subList(0, stack.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like this is off-topic, but I can't place how. Maybe that it's asking for "is this a good way", but I dunno if that's against the rules or not.

Comment: Yeah, needs to be synchronized. All of them.

Comment: depends on your business logic, whether multiple threads will visit the same CrumbNav instance. And you class seems like a simple wrapper around stack, if you want to use multithreading here, better create or use a "ConcurrentStack" to separating the business layer and data layer.

Comment: If you think they need to be synchronised, it is probably because you are encountering a problem. The way I see it, if you have a copy of this object per each user, and this object is stored in the user session, there is no need for it to be synchronised.

Comment: good question and I guess u have a good answer. plz **read about the happen-before relationship in java** to get more info

Comment: @qqibrow application is not creating any threads. only the web application user threads I am worried about really bit confused about heaps and stack, my understanding is all instances share the instance variables in the Heap and have their own copy of local variable.

Comment: yeah. I think you confuse stack as data structure and stack in process memory space. Why don't you do this? maintain a set in your class. Everytime the method been called, add currentThread.thread_id into the set. Then output the set at last, seeing that whether it's been called from multiple threads.

Comment: @Dima could you explain bit more, why I need to synchronise.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what web framework you're using as to if the object is created per-thread, or as a singleton for the entire session.  Spring will, by default, create a single instance and may require synchronization.  Other web frameworks may not.

Note that in the "happy path" world, there's only one active thread rendering a page for any given user, but there's nothing stopping the user from rapid-fire clicking on different link initiating many connections and therefore threads.

Comment: Note that I very much don't approve of this method.  I'm thinking there's a large number of contingencies that are being overlooked, but are outside the scope of answering this question.

Answer (score 1):

(I mentioned this in comments, I think it's better to make it an answer.)

There are so many web framework in the industry, who knows how they gonna use your class? The best way is to test whether multiple thread gonna access the same instance concurrently.

Maintain a concurrent set in your class. Every time the method been called, add currentThread.thread_id into the set. Then output the set at last, seeing that whether it's been called from multiple threads. If so, then rewrite your class to a thread-safe version.

Answer (score 1):

Tracking navigation is normally on a per user basis. This class contains storage of the navigation state - which is user specific state, so you need one instance per user session. The methods don't need to be synchronised unless there is the possibility of the same user re-entrantly entering the web server (as mentioned by PaulProgrammer).

Some frameworks will allow this. It can be prevented in Spring MVC by setting the synchronizeOnSession controller property, and there are likely similar techniques for other frameworks.